# Trouble converting data into datetime from a csv. in pandas

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I am trying to import a csv file into a pandas dataframe, merge four of its columns into a 'datetime' column, and set the datetime column as data type Datetime64.

This is a small sample of my raw data:

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
0, 3001, 1, 1,   0, 0,  5, 4, 1.00, 0, 0, 0 
1, 3001, 1, 1, 100, 0,  7, 5, 1.00, 0, 0, 0 
2, 3001, 1, 1, 200, 0,  9, 6, 1.00, 0, 0, 0 
3, 3001, 1, 1, 300, 0,  9, 7, 1.00, 0, 0, 0 
4, 3001, 1, 1, 400, 0, 11, 8, 1.00, 0, 0, 0
```

So far I have:

```
dateparse = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y %m %d %H%M')
Test = (read_csv(
   'file.csv',
   names=["year","month","day","hour","a","b","c","d","e","f","g"],
   parse_dates={"datetime": ["year","month","day","hour"]},
   date_parser=dateparse, 
   usecols=["year","month","day","hour","b"]
))
Test.head()
```

This appears to have worked for many other people, however it will not work here. This is what is produced:

```
index, datetime, temp_hmean
0, 3001-01-01 00:00:00, 4.7 
1, 3001-01-01 01:00:00, 3.4 
2, 3001-01-01 02:00:00, 5.4 
3, 3001-01-01 03:00:00, 4.3 
4, 3001-01-01 04:00:00, 5.5
```

I have also tried adding converting the 'datetime' column to datetime afterwards, as per other articles, but it does not work.

Here where you keep the original columns:

```
Test['datetime'] = Test.apply(
    lambda row: datetime.strptime(
        row['year']+ '-' + row['month']+ '-' + row['day']+ ' ' + row['hour'],
        '%Y-%m-%d %H%M'), 
    axis=1
)
```

OR here without keeping the originals:

```
Test['datetime'] = to_datetime(
    Test['datetime'], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
)
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Exactly the dataframe that was produced, but the datetime column should be in the data type datetime64, it comes out as an object.

Comment: do you have any NaNs or NaTs in the `datetime` column?

Comment: Converting to datetime64 should be trival. Have you tried something like this? `dateparse = lambda x: numpy.datetime64(datetime.strptime(x, '%Y %m %d %H%M'))`

Comment: There are no null values in any column.

Comment: @Hakin Lid No joy with: 'dateparse = lambda x: numpy.datetime64(datetime.strptime(x, '%Y %m %d %H%M'))' I get an error of TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given. It must be trying to use the function on all four "year","month","day","hour" columns instead of the new "datetime" one.